# Remove axis.titles in gg.gap () plots

Tags: ggplot2, plot, label, axis

Someone knows how to delete axis.title.y from a gg.gap() plot?
I'm trying using theme () but it doesn't work...

For example using a gg.gap() package example:
I did a ggplot without any y and x axis titles ("p" plot), but when I used "p" in gg.gap to create a gap in y axis, the axis titles appears again...

```
data(mtcars)
library(ggplot2)

p<-ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = gear, fill = gear)) +geom_bar() +ggtitle("Number of Cars by Gear") +xlab("Gears") + 
          theme( axis.title.y = element_blank(),
             axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
             axis.text.y = element_blank(),
             axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
             axis.text.x = element_blank())

pgg <- gg.gap(plot=p,segments=c(5,10),tick_width = c(1,10),ylim=c(0,50))
```

And neither theme() works...

```
pgg + theme( axis.title.y = element_blank(),
             axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
             axis.text.y = element_blank(),
             axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
             axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you tried `+ scale_y_continuous(name = "")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is interesting.  As @teunbrand mentioned, you should be able to fix this via `scale_y_continuous(name="")`, or my preference: `name=NULL`.  It doesn't work though in any permutation!

What seems to work is setting the axis title to `NULL` or `""` using `lab(y=...)` or `ylab()`.  I thought this worked wherever you added it, but seems that you need to add to the plot before applying the `gg.gap()` function:

```
# this doesn't work
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(NULL)
pgg <- gg.gap(plot=p,segments=c(5,10),tick_width = c(1,10),ylim=c(0,50))
pgg

# this doesn't work either
pgg + scale_y_continuous(NULL)

# this apparently won't work
pgg <- gg.gap(plot=p,segments=c(5,10),tick_width = c(1,10),ylim=c(0,50))
pgg + ylab(NULL)


# this works
p <- p + ylab(NULL)
pgg <- gg.gap(plot=p,segments=c(5,10),tick_width = c(1,10),ylim=c(0,50))
pgg
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! in my data I don't know why but the second way (pgg + ylab(NULL)) it doesn't work but the first one yes (p + ylan (NULL) and then gg.gap plot). So... Thank you very very much!!! It was very helpful!!

Comment: Yeah, like I said it was an interesting question. I'm not entirely sure why this works but not the scale_ functions